# What is the difference between function(int &a){ a = a + 2 } and function(int *a){ *a = *a + 2 }

Tags: c, reference, dereference

In C (not C++)

what is the difference between:

```
function(int &a)
{
    a = a + 2;
}
```

and:

```
function(int *a)
{
    *a = *a + 2; 
}
```

For what I understand they are the same no?

If there are differences can you explain them with examples?

Comment: `int &a` is not standard C code. It is C++. Are you learning C or C++? If you are learning C, the answer is not to use `int &a`; it is not valid. If you are learning C++, somebody may write an answer discussing differences between references and pointers. Pick one language, remove the tag for the other, and edit the question and title to clarify which language you are asking about.

Comment: The second form uses pointers.  The first form uses references, which are a C++ (not C) feature.  One way to think about references is that they are a restricted form of pointer.

Comment: This should not be closed as a duplicate until OP clarifies whether they are asking about C or C++. If they are asking about C, as they indicated, this is not a duplicate of that C++ question.

Comment: The net effect is the same for both but the reference version is preferred because nobody can set a reference to null accidentally

function(int *a)
{
     a = NULL ;
    *a = *a + 2;  // crash
}

Comment: @user3386109: It is not appropriate to remove the C tag when we do not know OP’s intent. OP may be learning C but have been confused by some C++ code they encountered, in which case this is a C question, should have a C tag, and should be answered that this is not valid C code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is indeed about C

Comment: @MiguelM Which compiler are you using?

Comment: The net effect is the same for both but the pointer version is preferred because it is absolutely clear, throughout the function, that 'a' is accessed indirectly because of the asterisk.  The use of C++ references, (and other such bodges, like var parameters in Pascal), cause more confusion than they are worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int &a` is not code defined by the C standard and generally cannot be used in C. In C++, this declares a *reference* to an object, which is like a pointer but does not require `*` when using the object that is pointed to, cannot be changed once created, and cannot use a null pointer.

For C++, differences between pointers and references are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in). In C, you cannot normally use `int &a`. (It could be used in some hypothetical C implementation that supported it as extension, which is how C++ originated.)